# Updating Column based on previous column Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have this column that is sequential based on check run on the previous column. When the check doesn't meet the criteria it returns a null. Now I want to return every value that comes after the null, as a null, since I don't need them. How do I do that?

I have these clients that come into a pharmacy and are given drugs for 30 days. A client is given a lee way of 7 days, after the 30 drug dose is completed. If he comes after the 7 days, he's restarted on the drugs, e.g if a client comes into the pharmacy on 2019-08-14 and given drugs, he's supposed to return for a refill on 2019-09-14 or any days within 7 days after that date.

```
SELECT Id,ClientID,VisitDate,PreviousVisitDate, rn, 
DATEDIFF(dd,PreviousVisitDate,VisitDate) As DaysBetweenVisit, 
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,PreviousVisitDate,VisitDate) <=37 THEN rn
     WHEN rn =1 THEN rn
END  rn_new
    FROM (
            SELECT Id,A.ClientId as ClientId, VisitDate, rn,
            CASE WHEN rn= 1 THEN NULL
            WHEN rn > 1 THEN LAG(VisitDate) OVER (ORDER BY ClientId)
            END as PreviousVisitDate

    FROM  [dbo].[SomeTable] A ) B; 

Id      ClientID        VisitDate   PreviousVisitDate   rn  DaysBetweenVisit    rn_new                              
25208   10269-07-2/18   2018-05-14  2018-04-11          2   33                  2 
44538   10269-07-2/18   2018-06-12  2018-05-14          3   29                  3 
44539   10269-07-2/18   2018-08-04  2018-06-12          4   53                  NULL 
44543   10269-07-2/18   2018-09-04  2018-08-04          5   31                  5 
44544   10269-07-2/18   2018-10-03  2018-09-04          6   29                  6
```

[image]

I want  5 and 6 to  in the last column to be  NULL's as they already encountered a null in the 4th sequence

Comment: please share your desired data as text rather than image.

Comment: Image is what i have achieved, my desired result is to have 5 and 6 in the last column to be NULLS

Comment: unfortunately, I can see that image as `enter image description here` , and I think many people may see as this.

Comment: Id    ClientID        VisitDate PreviousVisitDate rn DaysBetweenVisit rn_new
25208 10269-07-2/18 2018-05-14 2018-04-11 2 33 2
44538 10269-07-2/18 2018-06-12 2018-05-14 3 29 3
44539 10269-07-2/18 2018-08-04 2018-06-12 4 53 NULL
44543 10269-07-2/18 2018-09-04 2018-08-04 5 31 5
44544 10269-07-2/18 2018-10-03 2018-09-04 6 29 6

Comment: copy to notepad.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i can't seem to get the table formated accordingly in text...kindly copy to notepad to view it as a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure you're looking backward in your window function to check for other nulls. Without all your data we can't explicitly solve your problem, however this is an example of what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
ID INTEGER,
Seq INTEGER,
Val INTEGER,
RequiredValue INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1,1,NULL,1),(1,2,33,2),(1,3,29,3),(1,4,53,NULL),(1,5,31,5),(1,6,29,6);

SELECT *, IIF(NewRequiredValue = -1, NULL, RequiredValue) NewRequiredValue
FROM
(
SELECT *, MIN(ISNULL(RequiredValue, -1)) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Seq ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) [NewRequiredValue]
FROM @t
) a;
```

And here are the results:

```
ID          Seq         Val         RequiredValue NewRequiredValue NewRequiredValue
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ---------------- ----------------
1           1           NULL        1             1                1
1           2           33          2             1                2
1           3           29          3             1                3
1           4           53          NULL          -1               NULL
1           5           31          5             -1               NULL
1           6           29          6             -1               NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your datediff computation over a window of unbounded preceding to check if max value over the window >37

```
SELECT Id,ClientID,VisitDate,PreviousVisitDate, rn, 
DATEDIFF(dd,PreviousVisitDate,VisitDate) As DaysBetweenVisit, 
CASE WHEN MAX(DATEDIFF(dd,PreviousVisitDate,VisitDate)) over (partition by clientid order by VisitDate rows unbounded preceding) <=37 THEN rn
     WHEN rn =1 THEN rn 
END  rn_new
    FROM (
            SELECT Id,A.ClientId as ClientId, VisitDate, rn,
            CASE WHEN rn= 1 THEN NULL
            WHEN rn > 1 THEN LAG(VisitDate) OVER (ORDER BY ClientId)
            END as PreviousVisitDate

    FROM  [dbo].[SomeTable] A ) B
```

Answer (score 0):

Count previous `rn_new` which is by query design `rn` or `NULL` and compare it to `rn` which is by design 1..n with no gaps.

```
Select Id, ClientID, VisitDate, PreviousVisitDate, rn, DaysBetweenVisit
      , case when COUNT(rn_new) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY rn) = rn  then rn_new end rn_new
from (
   -- your query
) t
```